# Routing from one server to another with different interfaces

Tags: iptables, interface, firewalld

I have this topology

[image: topology]

Server A:

- eth0 IP: `10.10.20.11/24` and `10.10.20.13/24`
- eth3: `88.x.x.x` (vlan with id 10)
- primary gateway: GW2 (`10.10.20.3`)

Server B:

- eth0 IP: `10.10.20.23/24`
- default gateway: `server A` (`10.10.20.11`)

From outside I can ping the `88.x.x.x` IP. `Server A` can ping `Server B`. On `Server B` I disabled the firewall.

Now I am trying to route traffic from `88.x.x.x` `Server A` to `Server B` with the following rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
    <passthrough ipv="ipv4">-A PREROUTING  -t nat -p tcp -d 88.x.x.x   --dport X -j DNAT  --to-destination 10.10.10.23:Y</passthrough>
</direct>
```

Sysctl variables on `server A`:
During troubleshooting I've got some results:

- `tcpdump port X` on `Server A` shows packets
- no packets were shown for `tcpdump dst 10.10.10.23` on `Server A`.
- `tcpdump port Y` on `Server B` doesn't show anything.
- The following works on server a: `telnet 10.10.10.23 Y`

After disabling `rp_filter` I've got half-working topology - At least I've seen the redirected and DNATted packets in the tcpdump.

After this I've got following picture:

- Server A: `tcpdump -i any port X -n`

```
IP 85.x.x.x > 88.x.x.x.X
```

- Server A: `tcpdump -i any port Y -n`

```
IP 85.x.x.x > 10.10.10.23.Y:
```

- Server B: `tcpdump -i any port Y -n`

```
IP 85.x.x.x > 10.10.10.23.Y
```

I had extended the tcpdump filter to `port Y and icmp` and I've started see the `icmp admin prohibited` messages in the replies from `10.10.10.23` host. Then I've tuned the firewall rules on `server B` - `icmp` messages stopped.

Currently I have this routing configurations:
- `Server A`

```
ip -4 ru ls:
0: from all lookup local
32764: from 88.XX/27 lookup 2014
32765: from 10.10.20.11 lookup 1000
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default

ip -4 r ls table all:
default via GW1 dev eth3 table 2014
88.x.x.x/27 dev eth3 table 2014
default via 10.10.20.3 dev eth0 table 1000
default via 10.10.20.3 dev eth0
10.10.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.11
88.x.x.x/27 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 88.x.x.x
broadcast 10.10.20.0 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.11
local 10.10.20.11 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.10.20.11
local 10.10.20.13 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.10.20.11
broadcast 10.10.20.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.11
broadcast 88.x.x.x dev eth3 table local proto kernel scope link src 88.x.x.x
local 88.x.x.x dev eth3 table local proto kernel scope host src 88.x.x.x
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

- `Server B`

```
ip -4 r ls:
default via 10.10.20.11 dev eth0
10.10.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.23
```

I need to get Access to `Server B` through real IP (`88.x.x.x`) from outside.
What I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Paste the output of commands: `ip -4 a ls` and `ip -4 r ls` from server A and server B. Also run `tcpdump` on server B and check the source address of incoming packets.

Comment: @AntonDanilov Got now the TCPDumps for you.

Comment: Do you have on ServerB default gateway through ServerA or another device?

Comment: @AntonDanilov Yes. The default Gateway for ServerB is ServerA

Comment: On serverB check the output `ip route get 85.XX from 10.10.10.23` and output of `iptables-save -c`. If you don't see the replies on serverB, then something is wrong. ServerA configuration is Ok. so let's try to troubleshoot serverB.

Comment: Use the tcpdump filter `icmp or port X` instead `port X`. Maybe some `port unreachable` message is sent from serverB, but it isn't captured by `tcpdump` due by the filter expression.

Comment: @AntonDanilov Got this message: IP 10.10.10.23 > 85.X.X.X: ICMP host 10.10.10.23 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93845/discussion-between-anton-danilov-and-kordi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step to troubleshoot:

1. Check the actual routing. On server A run `ip route get 10.10.10.23 from 8.8.8.8 iif eth1`. You should see the valid route in the output of this command. If you see something `RTNETLINK answers: No route to host`, you have disabled forwarding. See the next step. Output like `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device` means `rp_filter` filters similar packets. You also can disable it completely or set into `loose` mode.
2. On server A check the forwarding (`ip netconf show dev <iface>`). It should be enabled (`forwarding on` in the output`). You can turn on it with`sysctl` command.
3. In the SNAT rule you should use `--to-source 10.10.10.Z`, where `10.10.10.Z` is address of `eth0` interface of server A. Otherwise there are side effects at translation of reply packets from the server B. If the default gateway of serverB is serverA, then SNAT rule isn't necessary.
4. Check the full ruleset on server A. Use `iptables-save -c` command to list all rules with counters. You should see non-zero counters in the rules of `FORWARD` chain.
5. Execute the similar steps for serverB: check the routing, check the firewall rule set, check the tcpdump output.
6. Run `tcpdump` on both hosts and check the traffic. The `tcpdump` captures incoming packets before firewall, but outgoing packets - after. Better include `icmp` in the tcpdump filters, otherwise you won't see the icmp rejects like `port unreachable` and similar.
7. When all step above is done, you should add these firewall rules into configuration of `server A` to make the replied packets from `server B` pass through `GW1`:

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD\
         -p tcp --dst 10.10.20.23 \
         -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdst 88.x.x.x --ctdir ORIGINAL \
    -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2014

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING \
         -i eth0 -p tcp \
         -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctdir REPLY \
    -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

And add an additional routing rule into PBR:

```
ip rule add fwmark 2014 lookup 2014
```

Comment: The ip route gives me the following answer `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link` and I have non zero counters [181:10816] -A PREROUTING -d  88.x.x.x ....